# Extract list of subwords from a dataframe without corpus

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

Actually i want to extract some list of subwords with in the data frame,I know we can extract through corpus but i dont want to do that unnecessary.firsstly i used **match** as well as **grep** but the problem is match cant be used other then exact match and grep cant be used for multiple words.for ex.

```
 a=sample(c("Client","offshor","V1fax","12mobile"),10)
 z=data.frame(a)
 z
          a
1     V1fax
2     V1fax
3  12mobile
4  12mobile
5     V1fax
6     clint
7   offshor
8     clint
9     clint
10 12mobile

d=z[is.na(match(tolower(z[,1]),c("fax","mobile","except","talwade"))),]

grep(c("fax","mobile","except","talwade"),tolower(z[,1]))
    [1] 1 2 5
Warning message:
In grep(c("fax", "mobile", "except", "talwade"  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

want an o/p to be as

```
z
       a
1     clint
2   offshor
3     clint
4     clint
```

as expected any efficient method to extract list of subwords.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `grep` you just need to use the regular expression `OR` operator which is `|`...

```
grep(  paste( c("fax","mobile","except","talwade") , collapse = "|" ) , tolower(z[,1]) )
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 10


#  The pattern...
paste( c("fax","mobile","except","talwade") , collapse = "|" )
# [1] "fax|mobile|except|talwade"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little slower than Simon's solution, but it gives access to a lot more data for analysis. You can use `sapply` to return a matrix of matches:

```
patterns  <- c("fax","mobile","except","talwade")
match.mat <- sapply(patterns, grepl, z$a)
rownames(match.mat) <- z$a

#            fax mobile except talwade
# V1fax     TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# V1fax     TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# 12mobile FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
# 12mobile FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
# V1fax     TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# clint    FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# offshor  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# clint    FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# clint    FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
# 12mobile FALSE   TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
```

With that matrix, you can answer a lot of things:

Did elements get at least one match:

```
rowSums(match.mat) > 0
#    V1fax    V1fax 12mobile 12mobile    V1fax    clint  offshor    clint    clint 12mobile 
#     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
```

Which ones:

```
which(rowSums(match.mat) > 0)
#    V1fax    V1fax 12mobile 12mobile    V1fax 12mobile 
#        1        2        3        4        5       10
```

For a particular word, what pattern(s) were matched and vice versa:

```
which(match.mat["12mobile", ])
which(match.mat[, "fax"])
```